# using Messages on a MacAir

Tags: macbook-pro

On my Mac Air, the return key sends the message, rather than moving my text to the next line. How do I move my text to the next line or can I change Preferences so that I can use the return key to advance to the next line and another command to actually send the message.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will insert a newline.